# How to exclude specific subdomains server_name in nginx configuration

Tags: nginx, nginx-location

I'm using wildcard in `server_name`. I want to redirect all subdomains of `example.com` (configured as *.example.com) to `foo.com` except `xyz.example.com`

I have configuration as follows

```
server {
        listen          80;
        server_name     *.example.com;
        location / {
            proxy_pass      http://$1.foo.com;
        }
}
```

I don't want to change any request coming to `xyz.example.com`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need at least two server blocks, and `nginx` will select the more specific server block to handle the request. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html) for details.

You will need a server block for `xyz.example.com` such as:

```
server {
    listen      80;
    server_name xyz.example.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://$1.foo.com;
    }
}
```

Then either a `default_server` or a wild card server, such as:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name *.example.com;
    return http://foo.com/;
}
```

Or:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    return http://foo.com/;
}
```

Comment: Why is this marked as "correct answer"? It's wrong and doesn't work!