# Nginx subdomains not working

Tags: nginx

I don't know what's wrong. I don't get any warnings in logs. I've similar config to this
[How to exclude specific subdomains server_name in nginx configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35037510/how-to-exclude-specific-subdomains-server-name-in-nginx-configuration)

I want to create subdomain us.example.io I'm using `ping` to check it

```
ping us.example.io
ping: cannot resolve us.example.io: Unknown host
```

nginx.config

```
 server {
    server_name *. us.example.io us.example.io;
    listen 80;
    root /usr/share/nginx/html/bint;
    index index.html index.htm index.php;
    location / {
      try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;   
    }
  }

  server {
    server_name us.example.io;
    listen 80;
    return http://www.google.com;
  }
```

Answer (score 7):

The problem has nothing to do with nginx. The error suggests that you haven't configured a DNS record for the domain.