# How can I get nginx to forward a shortname to a FQDM?

Tags: nginx

On our network our server is reachable by

```
appname and appname.companyname.net
```

How can we get it to forward 'appname' to 'appname.companyname.net'?

appname could vary so having it work with any value there would be wonderful.

This is running on AWS elastic beanstalk. We are configuring this via EB extensions which we can pass in a line to be added to the already existing ngnix server{}

Comment: I would have thought that a shortname could be handled the same as any unwanted subdomain. With a specific `server` block for the shortname or the FQDN. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35037510/how-to-exclude-specific-subdomains-server-name-in-nginx-configuration/35039222#35039222) for guidance.

Comment: @RichardSmith please read my last line in the question. We can't add additional server blocks as EB is putting our additions into an existing server block. We can add if() statements with return values.

Comment: Oops, I guess you'll have to use an `if` statement then.

Comment: As a newbie to this I struggling a bit with the nginx regex, return value, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be able to detect the shortname by looking at the `$http_host` variable and making a redirect to the FQDN. For example:

```
if ($http_host = appname) {
    return 301 $scheme://appname.example.com$request_uri;
}
```

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#if) for more, and [this caution](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/) on the use of `if`.

Comment: Wont $http_host == appname even when accessed via appname.companyname.net?

Comment: No, the value of the Host header in the HTTP request includes the entire hostname and optional port parts of the original URL.